# How to Print Module Descriptions from VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

**Problem**

Working on a documentation routine for an Access 2010 database. Within the database are numerous modules & classes. I can readily print names of these as well as Get/Set properties, but haven't found a way to retrieve the descriptions input via the VBE's module properties panel.

**Background**

Using the `Application.VBE.VBProjects` collection I can get at the names of the modules & classes using

```
'iterate through modules
For Each vbComp In vbProj.VBComponents
    Set vbMod = vbComp.CodeModule

    'fetch description
    Select Case TypeName(vbMod)
        Case "CodeModule" 'module
            'description = CurrentDb.Containers("Modules").Documents(vbMod).Properties("Description")
        Case Else
            description = ""
    End Select

    Debug.Print vbComp.Name
    Debug.Print description
Next
```

The `CurrentDb.Containers("Modules").Documents(vbMod).Properties("Description")` line errors out. It was a stab at getting at the description property, but no dice.

Got this far by checking out [Daniel Pineault's](https://www.devhut.net/2011/06/04/vba-vbe-enumerate-modules-procedures-and-line-count/) routines, but no searches have shown how to get at the module/class descriptions. You can get at the project description & table descriptions but no module/class descriptions. Retrieving them would significantly reduce documentation time.

**Question**

Any ideas on how to retrieve these descriptions?

Comment: `line errors out` does not describe the error that you are getting ... give us something to work with here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. The `Documents` collection needs a name (or index), not an object. Use `VBComp.Name` or `vbMod.Name`.

```
'fetch description
Select Case TypeName(vbMod)
    Case "CodeModule" 'module
        ' Handle modules without Description property
        On Error Resume Next
        Description = CurrentDb.Containers("Modules").Documents(VBComp.Name).Properties("Description")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Description = ""
        On Error GoTo 0
```

**Edit:**
Actually, the error handling is the more important part.

- Standard modules without description don't have an empty "Description" property, they don't have the property at all.
- Form/Report modules will also show up in this `Case`, but they aren't contained in `Containers("Modules")`. These modules don't have a separate description. If you want to print the Form/Report description instead, you'd have to add another case distinction.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent.  Made one adjustment using Nz for handling missing descriptions `description = Nz(CurrentDb.Containers("Modules").Documents(vbComp.Name).Properties("Description"), "")`